# Jquery hide/FadeIn problem using Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

This code works fine in IE8/7 and Firefox... But in Google Chrome i got a problem...

My page have a menu, when the user click it, hide div blocos and shows the content (using url parameter setted in menu)

My Jquery Code:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.blocos').hide();
        $('div#divMenuBloco').show();

```
    $('.clickable').click(function(){
        var _session = $(this).attr('url');             
        $('div.blocos').hide();
        $('div#' + _session).fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
}
```

MENU div item:
    
    ...

That part works Great... All menu links hide and fadeIn the content...

So I added a Link "Back" inside content div...

```
<div class="clickable" id="divBack" style="float:right;margin-right:25px;cursor:pointer" url="divMenuBloco">Back</div>
```

When user click on that, the "Start" content shows up, but it hides after ... Only in Google Chrome ...IE8 and Firefox 3.5 works fine...
Any idea?

Edited:
Html code:

```
<div class="moldura">
    <div class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="navegacao-principal">
            <div class="clickable" url="div1">
                <img src="Arquivos/Imagens/Estrutura/iconeLocalizacao.png"" />
             </div>
            <div class="clickable" url="div2">
                <img src="Arquivos/Imagens/Estrutura/iconePadrinhos.png" />
            </div>
        </div>

 <div id="divMenuBloco" class="blocos">
    <strong>HOME</strong><br />
    <div class="bloco clickable" url="div3">
       <strong>LINK 3</strong><br /> 
    </div>        
</div>

     <div id="div1" class="blocos">               
         "TESTE 1" 
         <div class="clickable" id="divBack" style="float: right; margin-right: 25px; cursor: pointer" url="divMenuBloco"> Back</div>
....
     </div>                          
 </div>
```

Comment: there is no div with the id 'divSatart' in the HTML you've given.

Comment: sorry... fixed... divStart = divMenuBloco

Comment: Do you have a DocType on the HTML Document?

Comment: It is a aspx page:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used "Show" instedOf "Fadein" and worked fine in Chrome !